# MYSQL join returning duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables,

1. Table `Manager-Employees` has employee & manager records. The managerid and employeeid are the key records. One manager could manage n or more employees.
2. Table `Employee` has employee records. Both manager & employee are in this table. The employeeId column is the unique id.

Below is my attempt to get the records from these tables that shows the managerid,employeeid,managername & employeename. This query is returning duplicate rows. How can i fix this? The database is ***mysql***.

```
SELECT 
    `employee`.`employeeId` AS `employeeId`,
    `manager_employees`.`managerId` AS `managerId`,
    `manager`.`fullName` AS `Manager Name`,
    `employee`.`fullName` AS `Employee Name`,
    `employee`.`employeeRoleTitle` AS `employeeRoleTitle`,
    `manager`.`employeeRoleTitle` AS `manageremployeeRoleTitle`
FROM
    `Manager-Employees` `manager_employees`
LEFT JOIN
    `Employee` `manager` 
    ON (`manager`.`employeeId` = `manager_employees`.`managerId`)
LEFT JOIN
    `Employee` `employee` 
    ON ( `employee`.`employeeId` =  `manager_employees`.`employeeId`);
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT will get rid of any duplicate rows.
Do you have duplicates in your Manager-Employees table ?

Comment: @GabrielDurac Thank you. Yes distinct will but i was wondering if there was a way of doing that without using distinct.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's pretty straight forward. There is a manager-employee table that has records for employees & their corresponding managers.It has employeeid & managerid. The Employee table has all employee records. An employee could be a manager. It has an employeeid field.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: "returning duplicate rows" is not clear. Neither is "get the records from these tables that shows". Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS LEFT JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking for duplicates in your `manager-employees` table. Or duplicate employeeids in your `Employee` table. If any of these 2 are true, you will get duplicates in your result and the only solution is using `select distinct` (or cleaning up your source tables)

```
SELECT `employeeId`,count(*) as cnt 
FROM `Employee`
GROUP BY `employeeId`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

SELECT `managerId`,`employeeId`,count(*) as cnt 
FROM `Manager-Employees`
GROUP BY `managerId`,`employeeId`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Apparently there were duplicate records in the employee table